# Gradle loaded Serenity libs to project libraries but can't see them further

Tags: java, gradle, bdd, libraries, thucydides

I have this build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.4.0")
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile('net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.4.0')
    testCompile('net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.4.0')
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
    testCompile('org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0')
    testCompile('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7')

}

gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
```

It loads serenity libraries to the project BUT some classes are not visible when compile:
[PageObject class is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhG03.png)

but it truly exists in External libs:

[Class in the libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAkZZ.png)

What should I do to make it be visible in test classes and page object classes?
Also when I import manually by entering full path to the library then gradle runner does not see those classes anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. Wrong compile scope was chosen. Need to be compile not testCompile.